# Open file using batch command

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, file-extension

I let say I have some files with the following file extension .abc
as you know it is possible to set default program to open these files. I was wondering, is it possible to set the default program for a file to be a BAT file (so far it is possible) and when ever I click it get as a parameter the name of the .abc file which associated with it.

I couldn't find anything related on google, thought you might have a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hardly programming related, but anyways...

First create a batch file that somehow processes its first input parameter `%1` as the file name of the file you clicked will be passed as the first parameter. Something simple like:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO %1
PAUSE
```

You then need to register your batch program to the file extension you like (e.g. `.abc`). A simple introduction how this is done can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307859?ln=en-us).

Hope that helps